# Which data type the enumerations are stored by the compiler?

Tags: c#, enums

In which data type are the enumerations stored by the compiler?

Comment: I'll give you an upvote you repeat the question once more. :)

Comment: Holy cow folks.  Give a newbie a break. English may not be his first language.  Enough with the down votes, already.

Comment: @PranayRana - per http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297597/what-to-do-with-user-asking-for-upvote-and-accept, please stop asking for upvotes and acceptance, this is not allowed.   Your comments have been flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - okies will take care next time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enum` default uses `int` datatype for storing value

you can set type for `enum` and override default datatype, but datatype must be  of  integral numeric type

Example :

```
enum Months : byte { Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun,
                 Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec };
```

Comment: Unless you specify a `byte`, or a `short`, or even a `long`.

Comment: @EBrown - agree but i think op asking about default

Comment: Plus one for a good answer rather than a snarky comment or down vote.

Comment: thanks for the -1 on correct answer cannot get better than this...